# Fifo sorting a sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called Transactions which looks like this:

```
Id | date | type | price | quantity | buysell
1  | 0001 |    1 |  1.00 |        3 |     buy
2  | 0002 |    2 |  5.00 |        1 |     buy
3  | 0003 |    3 |  0.30 |        2 |     buy
4  | 0006 |    1 |  1.50 |        1 |    sell
5  | 0007 |    4 |  7.00 |       12 |     buy
6  | 0011 |    2 |  6.00 |        1 |    sell
7  | 0015 |    3 |  0.50 |        2 |    sell
8  | 0016 |    1 |  1.50 |        2 |    sell
9  | 0017 |    ....
```

I need to find a way how to match all `sell` transactions to related `buy` transactions. This should be done in the fifo principle: In the example above, transaction `4` should match to `1`, `6` to `2`, `7` to `3` and `8` to `1` (depending on the `type`). Also the `quantity` field has to be considered - transaction `1` for example has two fulfilling sell transactions which sum up to the buy quantity of `3`.

Is there a way to achieve this with mysql or any other database system?

**Edit**

The desired resulset could for example be a table of all sell transactions and their related buy transactions:

```
Id | sellid | buyid
 1 |      4 |     1
 2 |      6 |     2
 3 |      7 |     3
 4 |      8 |     1
```

Based on this table, I can calculate margins or the time it takes to sell something (for example).

Comment: What does the desired result set look like? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

you may try the below model

```
select *,
(select sum(case when buysell='buy' then quantity else -quantity end) from yourTable  a
 where  a.type1=b.type1 and a.date1<=b.date1) bls
 from yourTable b order by type1,id
```